# negation of Set unused command

Tags: database, oracle

Is there any option available for restoring a column which is set unused by ALTER TABLE command?

Answer (score 2):

Setting a column as "UNUSED" is irreversible except by restoring the table from backup. It's very similar in effect to dropping the column (except that the data is not immediately removed).

[More info.](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=567809&start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

The data is still here but is not accessible. Your best bet is to [contact support](http://support.oracle.com), they may have undocumented methods to salvage some of your data. By the way they will also be able to assist you if you need help with the recovery process.